# Is there a way to reference a function declared inside a variable?

Tags: javascript

This question is more out of curiosity. Is there a way I can call bar() without calling foo() in the code below? Or does this completely anonymize bar()? Furthermore, is there any use case for this sort of syntax?

```
var foo = function bar() {
    console.log('test')
}

foo(); // 'test'
```

Comment: You can... but just *inside it*: https://jsfiddle.net/z3gj0pn7/

Answer (score 2):

It's because it's scoped inside the function. You can test like this.

```
var a = 1;
var foo = function bar() {
    a++;
    console.log('test');
    if(a < 3) {
        return bar();
    }
}

foo();
//test
//test
```

Comment: Why are you *returning* `bar()`?

Comment: Just so they can see it's being referenced/used.

Comment: Makes absolutely no difference, because you're not showing the returned value of `foo`, just using the `console.log("test")` to show that the reference works. Therefore, it can be just `if(a < 3) bar();`.

Comment: You're right Gerardo, just edited his answer. Seems a bit more cleaned up. Thanks guys.

Comment: Oh. Good call Gerardo.